# Error al pintar desde el evento clicked de un Jtable a JCombobox anidado

Tags: netbeans, jtable

Cordial saludo.
Lo que trato de hacer es usar el evento clicked en un Jtable para pintar cada objeto del formulario (JTextfield, JCombobox), pero, el error radica que tengo tres combobox que son anidados.
Al hacer clic, me sale el sgte error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to modelo.

Al seleccionar el registro que se tiene en dicho JTable, pinta todo los datos en los objetos menos en los combobox anidados.

Espero me puedan ayudar, agradezco de antemano.

```
Clase Vacunas
package modelo;

import controlador.Conexiondb;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Vacunas {
    
    private int idVacunas;
    private String Descripcionvacuna;

    public Vacunas(int idVacunas, String Descripcionvacuna) {
        this.idVacunas = idVacunas;
        this.Descripcionvacuna = Descripcionvacuna;

    }

    public Vacunas() {
    }

    public int getIdVacunas() {
        return idVacunas;
    }

    public void setIdVacunas(int idVacunas) {
        this.idVacunas = idVacunas;
    }

    public String getDescripcionvacuna() {
        return Descripcionvacuna;
    }

    public void setDescripcionvacuna(String Descripcionvacuna) {
        this.Descripcionvacuna = Descripcionvacuna;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getDescripcionvacuna();
        
    }
    
    public Vector <Vacunas> CargarVacunas(){
        
        Conexiondb con = new Conexiondb();
        Connection cn = con.getConnection();
        
        Vector<Vacunas> datos = new Vector<>();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            String SQL = "SELECT idvacunas, Descripcionvacuna FROM vacunas";
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Vacunas vac;
            vac = new Vacunas();
            vac.setIdVacunas(0);
            vac.setDescripcionvacuna("Seleccione...");
            datos.add(vac);
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                vac = new Vacunas();
                vac.setIdVacunas(rs.getInt("idvacunas"));
                vac.setDescripcionvacuna(rs.getString("Descripcionvacuna"));
                datos.add(vac);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
 
        }

        return datos;       
    }
}

~~~Clase LoteVacuna
import controlador.Conexiondb;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Vector;

public class LotesVacunas {
    
    private int idLotevacunas;
    private int vacunas_idvacunas;
    private String NumLote;

    public LotesVacunas(int idLotevacunas, int vacunas_idvacunas, String NumLote) {
        this.idLotevacunas = idLotevacunas;
        this.vacunas_idvacunas = vacunas_idvacunas;
        this.NumLote = NumLote;

    }

    public LotesVacunas() {
    }

    public int getIdLotevacunas() {
        return idLotevacunas;
    }

    public void setIdLotevacunas(int idLotevacunas) {
        this.idLotevacunas = idLotevacunas;
    }

    public int getVacunas_idvacunas() {
        return vacunas_idvacunas;
    }

    public void setVacunas_idvacunas(int vacunas_idvacunas) {
        this.vacunas_idvacunas = vacunas_idvacunas;
    }

    public String getNumLote() {
        return NumLote;
    }

    public void setNumLote(String NumLote) {
        this.NumLote = NumLote;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getNumLote();
    }    
    
    public Vector <LotesVacunas> CargarLotesVacunas(int id_vacuna){
        
        Conexiondb con = new Conexiondb();
        Connection cn = con.getConnection();
        
        Vector<LotesVacunas> datos = new Vector<>();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        
        try {
            String SQL = "SELECT idLotevacunas, Numlote FROM lotesvacunas WHERE vacunas_idvacunas="+id_vacuna;
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            LotesVacunas lvac;
            lvac = new LotesVacunas();
            lvac.setIdLotevacunas(0);
            lvac.setNumLote("Seleccione...");
            datos.add(lvac);
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                lvac = new LotesVacunas();
                lvac.setIdLotevacunas(rs.getInt(1));
                lvac.setNumLote(rs.getString(2));
                datos.add(lvac);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
 
        }

        return datos;       
    }
}

~~~Clase donde está el formulario con el Jtable
 public void clicTabla(){
        
        int linea = tablaGuardarVacunas.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel modelotabla=(DefaultTableModel) tablaGuardarVacunas.getModel();
        
        txtIdAdult.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 0).toString());
        txtNroIdentidad.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 1).toString());
        cboDocument.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 3).toString());
        cboNacionalidad.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 4).toString());
        
        txtPrimerNombre.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 5).toString());
        txtSegunNombre.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 6).toString());
        txtPrimerApell.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 7).toString());
        txtSegunApellid.setText(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 8).toString());
        
        cboTipoAfiliacion.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 9).toString());
        cboEPSVac.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 11));
     
cboVacunas.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getModel().getValueAt(linea, 18).toString());
        
        cboLotes.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 14));
        
        cboDosis.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea, 20));
        
String formatofecha=String.valueOf(tablaGuardarVacunas.getValueAt(linea,22));
        SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date fecha;
            try {
              fecha=(java.util.Date)s.parse(formatofecha);
              dtFechaAplica.setDate(fecha);
        
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
            
        
    }
```

En esta parte cargo los datos de la tabla, que viene de la base de datos:

```
public boolean PrepararTablaVacunas() {
        
        try {
            DefaultTableModel tab = new DefaultTableModel();
            tablaGuardarVacunas.setModel(tab);
            
            String sql = "SELECT ap.adultos_idAdultos, a.Nroidentidad, a.TipoDocumetos_idDocumetos, \n" +
                    "t.Tipodocumento, a.Nacionalidad, a.Primernombre, a.Segundonombre, a.Primerapellido, "
                    + "a.Segundoapellido, a.Tipoafiliacion, a.eps_idEPS, e.NombreEPS, "
                    + "ap.idAplicacionvacunaadulto, date_format(ap.Fechaaplicacion, '%Y - %m - %d') As Fec_Aplicación, l.Numlote, ap.vacunadores_idVacunadores, "
                    + "v.Nombrevacunadores, ap.vacunas_idvacunas, vac.Descripcionvacuna, d.idDosis, "
                    + "d.DescripcioDosis , ap.Lotejeringa, ap.Fechaaplicacion "
                    + "FROM dbvacuna.aplicacionvacunasadultos as ap\n"
                    + "JOIN adultos as a\n"
                    + "ON a.idAdultos = ap.adultos_idAdultos\n"
                    + "JOIN tipodocumetos as t\n"
                    + "ON a.TipoDocumetos_idDocumetos = t.idDocumetos\n"
                    + "JOIN eps as e\n"
                    + "ON a.eps_idEPS = e.idEPS\n"
                    + "JOIN vacunadores as v\n"
                    + "ON ap.vacunadores_idVacunadores = v.idVacunadores\n"
                    + "JOIN vacunas as vac\n"
                    + "ON ap.vacunas_idvacunas = vac.idvacunas\n"
                    + "JOIN lotesvacunas as l\n"
                    + "ON vac.idvacunas = l.vacunas_idvacunas\n"
                    + "JOIN dosis as d\n"
                    + "ON d.idDosis = ap.dosis_idDosis ORDER BY idAplicacionvacunaadulto ASC;";

            ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
            int cantCol = rsMd.getColumnCount();

            tab.addColumn("idAdultos");//_____________0
            tab.addColumn("Nro identidad");
            tab.addColumn("Id_Tipo documento");
            tab.addColumn("T. documento");//_____________3
            tab.addColumn("Nacionalidad");
            tab.addColumn("Nombre");
            tab.addColumn("Segundo Nombre");//_____________6           
            tab.addColumn("Apellido");
            tab.addColumn("Segundo Apellido");
            tab.addColumn("Afiliación");
            tab.addColumn("IdEPS");//_____________10
            tab.addColumn("EPS");
            
            tab.addColumn("Id Aplc. Adult");
            tab.addColumn("FechaAplicación");
            tab.addColumn("Nro_Lote");
            
            tab.addColumn("vacunadores_idVacunadores");
            tab.addColumn("Vacunador");//_____________16
            
            tab.addColumn("vacunas_idvacunas");
            tab.addColumn("Vacuna");
            
            tab.addColumn("Id_dosis");
            tab.addColumn("Numerodosis");

            tab.addColumn("Lotejeringa");//_____________21
            tab.addColumn("Fecha");
            while (rs.next()) {

                Object[] filas = new Object[cantCol];

                for (int i = 0; i < cantCol; i++) {

                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                    
                }
                tab.addRow(filas);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.print(e.toString());

        }
        return true;

    }
```

[image: Acá está las propiedades del vector vacunas.]

Comment: Hola @JavierLarios, para que podamos ayudarte, es necesario que nos muestres parte de tu código, te recomiendo hacer un tour por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como manejarte y como preguntar, de esa manera, evitarás que cierren tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo, añadido.

Comment: ¿En cuál línea te marca el error?

Comment: cboVacunas.getModel().setSelectedItem(tablaGuardarVacunas.getModel().getValueAt(linea, 18).toString()); Lo que pasa es al tratar de pintar desde el JTable, sale el error por el cast.

Comment: @JavierLarios, necesitaría ver la clase donde creas la tabla entera, para ver si le estás asignando el editor correspondiente a la columna que requiere los JComboBox, supongo que son **cboVacunas**, **cboLotes** y **cboDosis** y están lotes y dosis dentro de vacunas.. o no?.

Comment: a los combobox, les pasas un array de datos, o una cadena?.

Comment: Dependiendo de vacuans, se debería mostrar el lote y la dosis. Los combobox son añadidos por arrays.